# Using `set` doesnt apply at that point in time

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I noticed over and over again that if i did something like:

```
@property int x = 1;

...code...

set("x", 2);
print(x);
```

it will show it as 1.  The reason was that it doesnt necessarily execute this immediately.   So if i ever set a property I have always made it a point to never use it through the rest of the function.  I always believed that set was just called at the end of the current execution.

When dealing with functions a similar approach happens.

It will be assigned but outside the scope of the function.  So i would try something like observing it and awaiting for a change in state.

```
@property Function myFunc = null;
@reflectable
_myFunc(_) => true;

attached(){
  set("myFunc", _myFunc);
  print("is myFunc null: ${myFunc == null}");
}
```

will return True.

So I then would also try:

```
@Observe("myFunc")
functionObservation(_)=>print("Function Called");
```

but this would not fire.

My desired end state is that when i pass `myFunc` into another polymer element and try to do stuff with it on that class' attached, as such:

```
@property Function execFunc = null;
attached(){
  if(execFunc != null)
    execFunc();
}
```

so when passing it into another component there are issues.

I am not 100% sure if this is a life cycle issue, or a set error but it seems that when i do it in attached, OR define a future:

```
attached(){
  new Future((){
    execFunc()
  });
}
```

It will still not seem to be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

you should rewrite your props as setters and getters and use the setter for notification :

```
int _myProp;
@reflectable
int get myProp => _myProp;
set myProp(v) {
   _myProp = v;
   notifyPath('myProp');
}
```

Or use something like [autonotify](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autonotify_observe) to automatically get properties notified for you.

This way you are guaranteed that this code always stamp `5` in the console:

```
myProp=5
print("${myProp}");
```

regardless the possible async polymer setter behavior.